# Datatable search in nested table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I'm using metronic v5.0.7.1 i have a datatable which is contains nested array so i just want to search in this array.

I'm able to bind my case status like that;

```
{
    field: 'case.case_status',
    title: "Status",
 }
```

there is my search field;

```
    var query = datatable.getDataSourceQuery();

    $('#m_form_durum').on('change', function () {
      datatable.search($(this).val(), 'case.case_status');
    }).val(typeof query.case.case_status !== 'undefined' ? query.case.case_status : '');
```

After that im getting this error *`"Cannot read property 'case_status' of undefined"`*. How can I specify the nested field in this case?

By the way if I replace my field to `'count'` which is in my array instead of `'case.case_status'` its work very well. Just nested fields give this error.

*Also this is my sample data:*

```
[
 {
   "id": 93,
   "case": {
     "id": 99,
     "case_status": 1,
   },
   "user": "1",
   "count": "2",
   "created_at": "2018-02-08T09:00:00.884590+03:00",
   "modified_at": "2018-02-08T09:00:00.884612+03:00",
   "is_deleted": false,
 }
]
```